# How to make 3 corner rounded in FrameRenders in Xamrin.Form?

Tags: c#, listview, xamarin.forms, mvvm-light

I want to make BottomLeft, TopRight, TopLeft corner to rounded. I have tried with following. But, when text size is bit more, it doesn't show correct design.

I have added my code as following.

For better understanding, I have added image.

Render Code

```
public class ExtendedFrameRenderer : FrameRenderer
{
    public override void Draw (CoreGraphics.CGRect rect)
    {
        base.Draw (rect);
        var elem = (ExtendedFrame)this.Element;
        UIRectCorner cornerstoRound = UIRectCorner.AllCorners;
        if (elem != null)
        {
            cornerstoRound = UIRectCorner.BottomLeft | UIRectCorner.TopRight | UIRectCorner.TopLeft;
        }

        var path = UIBezierPath.FromRoundedRect(rect, cornerstoRound, new CoreGraphics.CGSize(8, 8));
        var maskLayer = new CAShapeLayer();
        maskLayer.Path = path.CGPath;
        this.Layer.Mask = maskLayer;
    }
}
```

View:

```
<Grid ColumnSpacing="2" Padding="5">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="15" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <local:ExtendedFrame Grid.Column="1" OutlineColor="Transparent" HasShadow="False"
                         BackgroundColor="#30a5da">
        <StackLayout Spacing="0">
            <Label TextColor="White"
                   FontFamily="SourceSansPro-Regular"
                   FontSize="16"
                   Text="{Binding Text}" />
            <Label Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1"
                   FontSize="12" HorizontalTextAlignment="End"
                   Text="{Binding MessageDateTime, StringFormat='{0:hh:mm tt}'}"
                   TextColor="White" />
        </StackLayout>
    </local:ExtendedFrame>
</Grid>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can do it in XF without overriding FrameRenderer. This will give you shape what you want. And if you don't override renderer, it should better handle content inside

```
    <Grid Margin="10" HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand">
            <Frame
                BackgroundColor="Red"
                CornerRadius="0"
                HeightRequest="50"
                HorizontalOptions="End"
                VerticalOptions="End"
                WidthRequest="20" />
            <Frame
                BackgroundColor="Blue"
                CornerRadius="10"
                HeightRequest="100">
                <StackLayout>
                    <Label
                        FontSize="17"
                        Text="long fake text text"
                        TextColor="White" />
                    <Label
                        FontSize="12"
                        HorizontalTextAlignment="End"
                        Text="05:30 AM"
                        TextColor="Yellow" />
                </StackLayout>
            </Frame>
        </Grid>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think that is more simple. This is my plugin for UWP. Maybe it'll help you. look at the customRender.[Link](https://github.com/migueBarrera/Xamarin.Plugins.RoundedFrame)

Comment: which one? I think you forgot to set link.